# Restangular chaining not working

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to use Restangular to chain calls to one(), and haven't figured out why this isn't working:

```
my_data = Restangular.one('mydata', 12345).one('foo', 789).get().then (some_data) ->
  $scope.data_numbers = some_data.data.numbers
```

This should generate a call to '/mydata/12345/foo/789' but the chaining doesn't work. Instead, I get the error "Undefined is not a function". When I set a breakpoint and look at the result of doing just:

```
my_data = Restangular.one('mydata', 12345)
```

I can see that singleOne is undefined:

```
my_data
> Object {id: 197330, singleOne: undefined, route: "revenue", getRestangularUrl: function, getRequestedUrl: function…}
```

That seems to be the problem, though that's a bit of a guess. According to the Restangular docs and my previous experience, all of this should work, so I'm puzzled. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. To keep from being blocked I'm using a temporary customGET() but that's not very nice, so... Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any other dependencies that are new in your app and could be conflicting? I see nothing syntactically wrong and, as you say, chaining in that manner should be no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Angular is a very recent addition to this application, and there's nothing else I can think of that would be conflicting. Zurb Foundation and jQuery are the only other JS components in place.